# Permalinks, edit the recordings and their conclusion the output from the custom database tables in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api

Has its own table in the wordpress dashboard. This table has records that are displayed using $wpdb from the database from my custom table. As these records make like posts  wordpress, to they can be edited in the wordpress dashboard, to each record had its own permanent link and at this link you can view that entry in your customized template. The type  records would be tied to this template. How to implement it? Permalinks, edit the recordings and their conclusion the output from the custom database tables in wordpress.

Comment: Why do you need a custom table for it. Would it not be better to implement it as a custom post type?

Comment: @shariqkhan So of course it would be easier, but I want to know how to do it all manually.